# Нахождение максимально приближенного значения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть у меня список

```
l = ["1","4","2"]
```

мне нужно найти максимально приближенное значение к последнему аргументу из двух первых,как это сделать наиболее опитмальнее.

Comment: @MaxU ну не для строк конечно ,заранее привести в int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = ["1","4","2"]
l = list(map(int, l)) # приводим все значения к int
a = l.pop() # получаем искомое число 
min_l = min(l, key=lambda x: abs(x - a)) # получаем число с минимальной разницей с искомым
print(min_l)
index_min_l = l.index(min_l) # Индекс найденного значения
print(index_min_l)
```

Comment: Не работает ошибка : 
AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'pop'

Comment: Странно, в консоли работает. Но поправил

Comment: А что нужно использовать чтобы вывести индекс найденного числа?Все , разобрался

Comment: @DoubleMid Обновил ответ